# Show specific field(s) from created content-type

Tags: views, nodes, entities, blocks

Question might be easy, but I have a problem. I created a content-type (page), made it as a block with Node Block module, put this block in content. But it prints all stuff: title, authored by, date and so on. But what I nead is to print only body. But there might be another case, when I want to print also a title.

So the question is in general, how to print fields that I want from content-type,  maybe there is a module for this or a more convenient way.

I'm using latest Drupal 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure this as a per content type level, not for each node in particular.

Edit the content type, go to *Node Block settings* and under *Default view mode* select a convenient value. Then, click on *Manage presentation* tab and select the same value you set previously under *Default view mode*, and finally configure the fields and positions you want to be rendered.

Comment: Yes, I'm still learning Drupal, so no coding needed in this case. Thank you for your answer anyway!

Comment: There is no coding involved in this procedure.